# Azure Storage: How To Move Container Data to Archive Tier

Tags: azure, containers, storage

I'm trying to set some lifecyle management rules on my AKS storage account.

Currently I was able to succesfully set the first one:
[image]

I want to add a second one to send the blobs to the archive tier after 1 year. But when I search the options there is not archive tier option. Only cool storage and delete.

[image]

Although in the docs they do mention about the archive tier:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers

Can anyony help me achieve this?

Comment: What’s the storage account kind? Please note that archive tier is not supported for all storage kinds.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this paragraph in the doc? Archive tier is only available for LRS.

> The archive tier is not supported for ZRS, GZRS, or RA-GZRS accounts.
> Migrating from LRS to GRS is supported as long as no blobs were moved
> to the archive tier while the account was set to LRS. An account can
> be moved back to GRS if the update is done less than 30 days from the
> time the account became LRS, and no blobs were moved to the archive
> tier while the account was set to LRS.